# Fermenting milk?

Tags: fermentation

Different animals' milk contains more sugar than others. I have read that the Huns drank [fermented horse milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumis), but what are the types of milk that are fermented around the world today?

Comment: It's called cheese!

Comment: [Rennet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rennet) is used to separate milk into solid curds for cheesemaking and liquid whey. [Kefir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kefir) is made by using [kefir grains](http://www.culturesforhealth.com/milk-kefir-grains.html) which ferments various types of milk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The many varieties of fermented milks from around the world which are distinguished by the type and specificity of the microorganisms used for fermentation, by preserving fresh animal milk (e.g. cow, goat, sheep, mare, buffalo, camel or yak).

[Dahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahi) from India is a type of set yoghurt made from cow or buffalo milks which contains bacteria like L.lactis subsp. lactis, S. salivarius subsp. thermophilus.

**Langfil** is a [traditional](http://www.organic-cultures.com/dairy_cultures/filmjolk_yogurt_starter) fermented milk product from Sweden, It is made by fermenting cow's milk with a variety of bacteria from the species Lactococcus lactis and Leuconostoc mesenteroides.

**Gariss** is an indigenous fermented milk of Sudan. The product is made from camel's milk by natural fermentation of milk in leather bags. Streptococcus 
infantarius subsp. infantarius are involved in fermentation.

**Yakult**, mixture of skimmed milk with a special strain of the bacterium Lactobacillus casei Shirota. It was created by Japanese scientist Minoru Shirota.

Comment: I prefer your answer to my own.

Answer (score 2):

Camel's milk is fermented in many places.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chal) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_milk%20on%20Wikipedia) is some info for you.  Ewan McGregor and Charlie Boreman drank it in Mongolia during the filming of [The Long Way Round](http://www.longwayround.com/).  It was warmed over a stove that was fueled by camel dung, which apparently gave it an 'earthy' taste.

In Kazakhstan it’s known as 'Shubat' - [and you can buy it in the supermarkets](http://foodperestroika.com/2015/12/13/shubat-central-asian-fermented-camels-milk/).

Known as [Kefir](https://authoritynutrition.com/9-health-benefits-of-kefir/), milk is fermented using grains - which produces what some say is a superior product to yogurt.